# I used to run successfully before, Now I see runtime error the code gets compiled without an issue

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, runtime-error, typescript-class

I'm new to TypeScript. I was working with Class in the TypeScript and my code was working previously but now it is not working. It showing the error on RunTime.

[image]

Comment: Help us help you - please share the code and the error as (formatted) text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: Hi Mureinik, I've posted his code below in my comment. Kindly advise.

Comment: Hi @Mureinik can you please resolve the error

Answer (score 0):

```
class NewP {
    firstName : string;

    constructor(digit: string){

        this.firstName=digit;
    }

    greet(){

        return "Hi, " + this.firstName;
    }

}

let greet = new NewP("Hello");
```